# IntelliJ/Android -> "java: constant expression required" on case R.id.viewId

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

When I try to build my Android project in IntelliJ i get error´s on every switch statement which cases use Id´s out of the R.java.

Example:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {

  case android.R.id.home:
    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, DashboardActivity.upIntent(this));
    return true;

  case R.id.orders_options_add:
    handleAddItem();
    return true;

  case R.id.orders_options_reorder:
    handleReorder();
    finish();
    return true;
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Check so you haven't gotten any erroneously R-imports in the class.

Answer (score 12):

Resource ids are not constants in a library project since ADT version 14, so you can't use them in switch statement. Just use `if () {} else if () {} ...` instead.

You can find more detailed information [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields).

Comment: This counts only for resources that don't get created by your own app.

Comment: nope, it counts for any resources created in a library project

Comment: You are **wrong**. And it clearly says so multiple times in that link that it is only related to a **library** project.

Answer (score 1):

Add these two lines of code inside gradle.properties

```
 android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
 android.nonFinalResIds=false
```